# Safari and iPhone not rendering HTML code at all

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble with a page I'm making on my work and I can't seem to find the solution to it.

The problem is I have an internet application and it displays correctly on Windows and Mac (using other browser than safari) however it doesn't render on Safari (for Mac users) and it doesn't render at all on any browser while using an iPhone.

I tried adding the

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

line and also on my web controller I have this:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

And still instead of showing the rendered page all I can see is the HTML code itself.

Here you can look at my HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/custom.css}"
              href="../../custom.css" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <img alt="" th:src="@{/img/logo.gif}" />
            <h1>Hello </h1>
            <h2>Some other text 
            </h2>
            <form action="/confirm" method="POST" class="form">
                <div th:if="${variable1==true}"><input type="checkbox" name="variable1"/>Option 1</div>
                <div th:if="${variable2==true}"><input type="checkbox" name="variable2"/>Option 2</div>
                <div th:if="${variable3==true}"><input type="checkbox" name="variable3"/>Option 3</div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
                <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <input type="hidden" th:name="id" th:value="${id}" />

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my controller's get method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        System.out.println(response.getContentType());//Verifying this has been set
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        try {
            if(id==null) throw new Exception("Error del ID");
            List<Boolean> yesOrNo = icfi.getSiONo(id);
            model.put("variable1", yesOrNo.get(0));
            model.put("variable2", yesOrNo.get(1));
            model.put("variable3", yesOrNo.get(2));
            model.put("id", id);
            return "index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }

    }
```

I don't know if it's relevant but I'm using thymeleaf (in case you find the th: attributes disturbing) and Spring.

I'm adding some of the text I have on the properties file names application.properties:

```
#application.thymeleaf.templatesdir is relative to application path
application.thymeleaf.templatesdir = resources/templates/
application.thymeleaf.cache = false
#Undertow seems to read files only in Windows-1252 enconding.
application.thymeleaf.encoding = Windows-1252
application.thymeleaf.mode = HTML5
application.thymeleaf.content-type = text/html # ;charset=<encoding> is added
application.thymeleaf.suffix = .html
```

Comment: What happens when you view source from the Safari browser? [http://ccm.net/faq/33026-safari-view-the-source-code-of-a-webpage](http://ccm.net/faq/33026-safari-view-the-source-code-of-a-webpage)

Comment: It disables the button show page source, and so I can't see it however I think it would show exactly what it shows right now, the HTML code shown above.

Comment: Trying to determine if it shows HTML encoded characters, which are displaying literally, or if it's actually dumping source like a text file.  I think the options are probably that your editor is saving it as HTML encoded or you have a content-type issue. Do Safari's developer tools allow you to see the response headers?